# Extending function on semialgebra to measure on algebra requires non-negativity? Durrett Probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

In the 1st section of the appendix of Durrett's probability theory and examples, he said the following:

Theorem A.1.1 Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semialgebra and let $\mu$ defined on $\mathcal{S}$ have $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. Suppose (i) if $S \in \mathcal{S}$ is a finite disjoint union of sets $S_i \in \mathcal{S}$, then $\mu(S)=\sum_i \mu\left(S_i\right)$, and (ii) if $S_i, S \in \mathcal{S}$ with $S=+_{i \geq 1} S_i$ then $\mu(S) \leq \sum_i \mu\left(S_i\right)$. Then $\mu$ has a unique extension $\bar{\mu}$ that is a measure on $\overline{\mathcal{S}}$ the algebra generated by $\mathcal{S}$. If the extension is $\sigma$-finite, then there is a unique extension $v$ that is a measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{S})$.

Proof Lemma 1.1.7 shows that $\overline{\mathcal{S}}$ is the collection of finite disjoint unions of sets in $S$. We define $\bar{\mu}$ on $\overline{\mathcal{S}}$ by $\bar{\mu}(A)=\sum_i \mu\left(S_i\right)$ whenever $A=+_i S_i$. To check that $\bar{\mu}$ is well defined, suppose that $A=+_j T_j$ and observe $S_i=+_j\left(S_i \cap T_j\right)$ and $T_j=+_i\left(S_i \cap T_j\right)$, so (i) implies
$$
\sum_i \mu\left(S_i\right)=\sum_{i, j} \mu\left(S_i \cap T_j\right)=\sum_j \mu\left(T_j\right)
$$

In Section 1.1 we proved:...

> He did require measure on algebra to be non-negative, but he never said so for $\mu$. So I wonder if that's a typo? In fact, I don't understand why he would require $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$, but not the nonnegative requirement.

Durrett never defined measure for semi-algebra, so I assume $\mu$ is just some function.